# Semantically appropriate input title and field tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a form that lists the name of the input, the input, and possibly some help text. It is generally going to appear to be tabular, but I don't want to use a `table` or `div` because I imagine there is a more semantically-appropriate option by now.

Here is what it would look like without styles:

```
Name:    <name input>
Address: <address input>
         <address help info>
Phone:   <phone input>
```

Notice how it all lines up like a table.

Any ideas for the most appropriate HTML for this?

Comment: You have a good imagination. Use a table. :-)

Comment: @isherwood he said he does not want to use a table. Remember semantic elements just really describes the content of the element and does not manipulate the content in any way.

Comment: Well, yes, but for poor reasons. At any rate, semantics are perhaps most relevant in accessibility scenarios. Tables have a lot to offer for screen reader users, and seem quite appropriate here.

Comment: http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element). It got redefined in HTML5 so that it’s a "description list" instead of a definition list.

```html
<dl>

  <dt>Name:</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

  <dt>Address:</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

  <dt>Phone:</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

</dl>
```

If it’s a form with `input`, don’t forget to use [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/forms.html#the-label-element).

Note that it’s not "required" to use an additional structure, so a form like this is totally fine without `dl`/`table`:

```
<label for="form-name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="form-name" name="form-name">

<label for="form-address">Address:</label>
<textarea id="form-address" name="form-address"></textarea>

<label for="form-tel">Telephone:</label>
<input type="tel" id="form-tel" name="form-tel">
```

Answer (score 4):

Why is a table not semantically-appropriate if the data will appear tabular? Use a table, problem, solved.

Answer (score 1):

A real good question for which it's hard to find *one* correct answer. According to what I've found, either a `table` and `div` would be OK. Even though I would agree neither one of them *feels* like a real good solution.

### Tables:

At http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element it says:

> Tables should not be used as layout aids.

...and...

> [...] tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout making it difficult to extract tabular data from such documents.

But you're not really using tables for layout purposes here. You would be using it to present the form input data in a readable manner. As stated in the following sentence (also found in the table spec):

> The table element represents data with more than one dimension, in the form of a table.

To me, that means it should be OK to use tables in this case.

### Divs

Regarding the `div` the W3 spec says:

> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable.

But when reading the `section` spec it says this about the `div`:

> When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

To me, that means that you can also choose to use `div` for styling or layout purposes. I've tried to put togehter some thoughts about the use of `div` in this blog post: http://htmlusedtobeeasy.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/divisions-and-sections/

Sorry for the long answer (my first), hope it helps!